# Does ASP.Net MVC4 Cache References?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I ran into an issue today that is making me pull my hair out.

I've created a WCF service which is fairly simple as it only exposes two operations and no data contracts.  This WCF service sits on top of a business logic layer.  Inside this business logic layer is a dll which exposes some contracts (just plain interfaces).

I've also created two test clients for the service.  One is a console client and the other is a MVC4 application.  Both reference the same endpoints and they both reference, through a project reference, the contract dll.

Now, all is fine until I change the contract by adding or removing a method, or even changing the signature of an existing method.  At that point my MVC4 app blows and throws all over the place.  Keep in mind that I'm not changing the WCF contract, just some internal contracts.

The reason is that inside of the business logic layer I am initializing my AutoMapper profiles via a static constructor.  Inside this static constructor I basically get all the assemblies of the current domain and iterate through them looking for objects that implement IProfile.  It's when I start trying to get types out of one of the dlls that reference the contracts dll that I get a fatal exception:  System.TypeLoadException.

Now, the console client behaves just fine.  Again, referencing the same dll's through a project reference.  I can change that contracts dll all day long and it's just happy as a lark, but MVC4 blows chunks.  If I go back and make the interface exactly like it was before MVC4 is happy.

I noticed that the path to the assembly that was failing to load is in the Temporary ASP.Net files location.  I blasted that entire directory and still no luck.

I can supply code, but it might be better if I gave you a dependency graph.  There's already about 5k lines of code in the BLL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you updating service reference after making changes to WCF? You have such option when right-clicking on service reference in your MVC project

Comment: I'm not changing the WCF contract, just some internal shared contracts.  So a shared dll between both the WCF and the MVC app is changing.  I didn't think I needed to update the service reference for a shared dll, but I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm suspicious about "one of the dlls that reference the contracts dll". Are you certain that dll is being rebuilt after you change the contracts dll? I've had cases where a project was accidentally using an assembly reference rather than a project reference, causing problems like those you describe. Have you decompiled the assembly which triggers the problem to double check that it's up-to-date?

Comment: See, that's the strange thing.  So what I did was remove an interface entirely (I pushed it lower - I didn't need to expose it at the API level).  So when I load the dll through a console program it's just fine - I can reflect and see the two interfaces that are in the contract.  On MVC, and only MVC do I get the error.  After checking the type that was causing the error (in the loader exception) I noticed it shows THREE interfaces.  Also the assembly location is in a folder under the temporary ASP.Net folder.  That's what made me think of some kind of caching - all my references are project.

Comment: cont.  That also doesn't explain why the console program, which calls the same endpoints as the controller in my MVC app, works fine no matter what changes I make to the interfaces.  One change to the interface makes MVC go haywire.  It's almost like MVC is ignoring any changes to project referenced dlls and is always keeping around an old copy.  Oh, and removing and re-adding the reference does nothing.

Comment: At what point in the first request is your static constructor fired? The only place I know of in MVC where assembly caching might happen is in Razor template compilation...

Comment: Also, I assume you're using regular IIS to host this app. Do you get the same behavior if you run it in IIS Express?

Comment: It's firing in a controller action which is called from ajax in the client.  I'm using IIS Express to host.  I haven't tried hosting in regular IIS yet, but I'll give that a try also.